# Running the compiled gtk4 C application will screw up my screen's resolution?

Tags: c, windows, gtk, gtk4

Does anyone has this running when they running the compiled gtk applications, their task bar goes missing? or rather go below the screen(i cant see my taskbar anymore). I installed my gtk with msys2 on Windows 10 and using the mingw gcc compiler from msys2 too. I have to go and reset my resolution everytime i runs the exe. why is this happening ? the compiled exe file i am running is just the simple helloworld gtk from the official gtk docs

https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), button);

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

I currently set up my vscode to compile automatically but I have tried the one given by the official docs as well. Its the same thing

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk4)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the source code as text and format it as a code block. What OS and compiler do you use? How did you install the GTK libraries and which version? Show the commands to compile and link your program.